# The executable permission of file after downloading is getting changed. Is there any protocol or way to intact the permission?

Tags: python, django, linux, download, chmod

I have deployed a Django application on AWS EC2 and application is targeted for Linux desktop users. There are some files which get downloaded in browser when clicking some links and are meant to be run by clicking on the files.

I am setting the permission of the file to executable before deploying but the file permission gets changed after downloading. I am using the HTTPS protocol. Is there any protocol or way to keep the permission of files after downloading so users don't need to do chmod in terminal?

The executable files are generated by using tool pyinstaller.

Comment: OS X will likely set the [quarantine bit](https://superuser.com/q/526920/173513), too. It still won't run even with `chmod +x`.

Answer (score 0):

No way, that would be far too dangerous.

That's why apps are installed via package installers, that have a script that sets the permissions correctly and gives the OS a chance to ask users if they are sure they know what they are doing.